Присваивание значения члену структуры с именем
typedef struct sMy
{
    int v1;
    int v2;
} My;

My s_val = {
    .v1 = 0x20,
    .v2 = 0x30,
};


Я изучал исходный код одной программы, встретил такое необычное использование структур- когда внутри объявления структуры используется точка и имя члена структуры потом операция присваивания и значение например .v1 = 0x20. Как эта фитча называется и в каком С++ (11,14,17) это появилось, где почитать?

"designated initializer", появились в C++20 и C99 (но большинство компиляторов разрешало их и в более старом С++ как нестандартное расширение).
